# Motion tracking image missing in other computer

Tags: image

I made something in Blender and added motion tracking but, when I move my blender file to other computer, the image that I used in motion tracking disappear in my blender file.

Actually I saved like this: *Pack into blender file* and *Save*.

Other external files like texture and so on.. are appear but, the image that I used for background in motion tacking is gone,....

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is not supported at the moment, reload your files manually (properties panel > reload footage)

Comment: As far as I know image sequences and movies are never packed into the blender file. Move them manually along with the file, also consider using relative paths.

Answer (score 1):

Image sequences or video used for motion tracking can't be packed into the .blend file.

You need to copy the image sequence or video to the new computer. On the new computer you need to reload the footage.