# Why did my tracks disappear?

Tags: tracking

I <kbd>shift</kbd>-clicked the X, next to the `F` for saving a data block; did I just erase all the info from the solve?  I thought the tracking info was linked to the Camera, not the video clip?

Also, I moved file locations of both the .blend file and the movie clip file.  Moving the movie clip file seemed to "unlink" the tracks from the movie clip, I re-opened the movie clip file and it was now Movie-Clip.001, but at that point the tracks were still there, linked to the camera.

Now, after <kbd>shift</kbd>-clicking the X for the movie clip data block thing (and saving, closing blender, and re-opening blender), it's all gone, no tracks, no markers, the camera doesn't move or anything....  I'm going to re-track the movie clips; I just want to know what NOT to do next time.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: All tracking information (camera and trackers) is uniquely associated with the video.  Why would you want to unlink it?

Comment: I wanted to send a clean file to someone.. lol.  TY

Comment: The video file does not get saved as part of the file. Blender does not save images in the .blend file. Read [Video tracking image missin in other computer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57378/motion-tracking-image-missing-in-other-computer/57399#57399)  also, to re-link your video read: [how-do-you-restore-previously-tracked-footage](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131922/how-do-you-restore-previously-tracked-footage)

Comment: Read also: [when I open up my file in blender the reference picture is gone](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44225/why-is-that-when-i-open-up-my-file-in-blender-the-reference-picture-is-gone)

Answer (score 1):

**To fix the file location issue I did:** Outliner > change the "display mode" to "Data API" instead of "View Layer or "Scene" > scroll down to Movie Clips and in there I found the file paths from Movie Clip and Movie Clip.001 and just copy/pasted <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> the correct file path.

<strike>Still not sure how to fix the deleted solve data/track data.</strike>

Best I can tell is <kbd>shift</kbd>-clicking the **X** for the Movie Clip data block (deleting the false user) and then saving the blend file permanently deletes the solve/track data and the clip must be re-tracked and re-solved.  *"Ten four rubber ducky. Over and out."*